# Do Memory Mapped Files need Mutex when they are read only?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Recently, something happened with our windows c/c++ applications.

We use a DLL to map files to page file, and our applications read these shared files through memory mapping.

Everything is OK when we just run a single instance of application.

Sometimes we get nothing(just zeros) -- but not error or exception -- from mapped memory when we run 24 instances at  the same time.

It seems like that this problem happens more on a slower storage device.
If the files are stored in a slower device(say, EFS of AWS), we got this problem about 6/24 instances every time.
But if we move files to EBS of AWS, we only got this problem about 1/24 or 2/24 instances, and not every time.

I guess maybe there are some conflicts during massive accessing?
Do I need mutex for these read only files?

The mutex is just for protecting writable objects, am I right?

More information:
Everything happened INSIDE that DLL.
EXEs just use this DLL to get TRUE or FALSE.
The DLL is used to judge whether some given data belong to a certain file.
Some structs describe the data structure of files, the problem is that a certain struct just get 0 when it should not, but not every time.
I logged the parameters inside the DLL, they are passed to DLL correctly, every time.

Comment: Where are you **writing** to them?!

Comment: I'm not sure what are the exact functions you are using for the operations that you describe, specifically for "our applications read these shared files". If you are using some function to perform this "read" operation, is it possible that this function can fail, and when it fails it returns all 0's (or nothing)?

Comment: You can have any number of concurrent readers of a mapped view of a file without needing any synchronization. Synchronization is required if there is at least a single writer involved. Without a [mcve] it's impossible to determine whether what you state and what your code does are the same thing.

Comment: @Orielno We do not use windows api function to read those files. We defined some global structs inside that DLL, and just call functions inside that DLL to get those structs' data.

Comment: @hzh is it a DLL that you implemented, or someone else did? If it is soomeone else, did you check if these functions can fail, and what may happen upon different types of failure?

Comment: @IInspectable That is what I want to know. In fact, I have a test program, but it got different results on three different platform. It's totally OK on my development environment, but sometimes happens on my test environment(AWS EBS), and happens every time on production environment(AWS EFS).

Comment: @Orielno Yes, everything happened INSIDE that DLL. EXEs just use this DLL to get TRUE or FALSE. The DLL is used to judge whether some given data belong to a certain file. Some structs describe the data structure of files, the problem is that a certain struct just get 0 when it should not.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala We do not write to them. DLL maps files to memory, and use structs to define data of files. EXEs call a certain function of DLL, pass some data, and get TRUE or FALSE only. DLL gets data from EXEs, and judge whether data belong to specific structs. The problem is, we can not get correct data through those structs every time.

Comment: A file does not have any data unless something writes to it at *some* time... When did these writes happen to wherever they did happen?

Comment: anyway the answer to the question: "do you need a mutex for multiple readers when there are no writers keeping the file open" should be "no".

Comment: How does the DLL map the files to memory?

Comment: @ssbssa We use CreateFileMapping API to do that.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The files already exist before EXEs are running, that's why I said we do not write to them. We load some existing files(have data in them) to page file, and judge whether other data belong to them.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know how and why did this happen, but I found that I can avoid this problem simply by adding a RETRY to that judge function.

I still think this problem is a kind of I/O problem because RETRY can avoid this, but I have no more evidences.

And, maybe the title is not very proper to this problem so I think it's time to close it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured it out.

This is NOT a memory mapped file problem, it is a LOGICAL problem.

Our DLL has not enough authority, so when we shared our data into memory, NOBODY can see them!

And our applications are designed to load data themselves if they can not find any shared data, so the difference of EFS and EBS happens!

These applications are very old, no documents left, and nobody knows how they are working, so I had to dig information from source code ...

Comment: Why did you answer your own question _twice_? Just update your original answer instead of spamming